# Ansible install msi using windows_package module

Tags: windows, powershell, ansible, ansible-inventory, ansible-template

I am trying to install Scale Out Software on my windows server.

Instructions given by scale-out software for unattended installation are [here](https://static.scaleoutsoftware.com/docs/user_guide/installation/windows/steps.html#unattended-installation)

According to the instructions, when I download the soss manually and run the below command in normal Powershell I am unable to install soss. However, when I open the PowerShell in a run as Admin mode I am able to install it.
Here is the command I ran from admin PowerShell
`msiexec.exe /i "C:\GCMS\soss.msi" /quiet INSTALLLEVEL=500`

Now I am trying to use the Ansible windows module but am unable to figure it out.

Here is my Ansible sample snippet

```
- name: Install Scaleout Host Service
  hosts: "LkmsCG4server"
  serial: "{{ scaleout_install_max_concurrency | default(1) }}"
  become_method: runas
  tasks:
    - block:
        - name: Initialize Facts
          set_fact:
            playbook_failed: false

        - name: Install and configure hosts
          import_tasks: ../../Tasks/scaleout/ScaleOutRunInstaller.yml
          ignore_errors: yes
          become: yes
          become_user: Administrator
          vars:
            scaleout_install_type: client
            ansible_become_user: '{{ service_user | default(ansible_user) }}'
            ansible_become_pass: '{{ service_password | default(ansible_password) }}'

##above playbook will be calling the below task

---
- name: Download and run Scaleout Installer
  block:
  - name: Create a temporary directory for the Scaleout installer
    win_tempfile:
      state: directory
    register: soss_installer_dir

  - name: Download Scaleout Installer
    win_get_url:
      url: "{{ installer_url }}"
      dest: "C:\\gcms\\soss.msi"
    retries: 3
    delay: 10

  - name: Run Scaleout Installer
    win_package:
      path: "C:\\gcms\\soss.msi"
      product_id: "{{ installer_product_id }}"
      creates_path: "{{ installer_install_path }}"
      arguments: '/i /quiet INSTALLLEVEL=500'
      state: present
    register: soss_msi_out
```

Ansible is being installed as a local admin user but still I am trying make it run as ad administrator to see if it works but it is not
I am able to see the soss.msi is being downloaded in the folder but not being installed.

Can someone point me in the right direction about what I am doing wrong?

Comment: cannot recognize an error, you will have to run it with `-vvvv` and see the error plus what's being run. the msi output will be insufficient unless you turn on msiexec debugging.